# Como excluir os últimos caracteres de uma coluna?

Tags: python, pandas

Estou no Jupyter Notebook trabalhando com Python, utilizando Pandas.

Estou trabalhando em uma planilha com 4 colunas.

Na coluna ('Data Inicial'), preciso remover os 9 últimos caracteres.

O primeiro caractere que preciso remover seria um "espaço" em seguida o horário, ex:" 08:41:00".

Anexo imagem para deixar mais claro.
[Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIQGd.png)
[Código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbuGe.png)

Comment: Salve! O Stack Overflow não é uma plataforma para encomenda de código ou pedidos de solução de trabalhos acadêmicos, e sim de solução de problemas ou dúvidas concretos em código existente. Poste o que você já fez e onde se comporta diferente do esperado.

Comment: Boa tarde.
Meu problema é o seguinte:

Preciso remover os 9 últimos caracteres da coluna "Data inicial" ou manter os 11 primeiros caracteres da coluna "Data Inicial"
Borrei o print pra não divulgar nomes de pessoas reais e seus clientes por questões éticas. 

Não faço ideia de como remover parte da informações dentro de uma coluna inteira.

Comment: Acabei de anexar outro print do código, acredito que fique mis claro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formata sua coluna assim, não é a melhor forma, mas funciona.

`seudf['Data Inicial'] = seudf['Data Inicial'].astype(str).str[:-8]`

Existem métodos melhores utilizando bibliotecas de datas e etc..

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou certinho!!
Muito obrigado.